# Slow pbpaste / pbcopy

Tags: macos

Laptop: Late 2013, i7, 500G SSD, 16G of ram

El Capitan 10.11.1

When I try and pbcopy and pbpaste on the command line they are running *awfully* slow. This ties into an emacs issue I'm having as well but since pbcopy/paste is the root of it I'm asking here....

Here is some example output:

```
~❯ time echo 'test' | pbcopy
echo 'test'  0.00s user 0.00s system 24% cpu 0.003 total
pbcopy  0.01s user 0.01s system 1% cpu 0.830 total
~❯ time echo 'test' | pbcopy
echo 'test'  0.00s user 0.00s system 38% cpu 0.002 total
pbcopy  0.01s user 0.01s system 1% cpu 0.847 total
~❯ time echo 'test' | pbcopy
echo 'test'  0.00s user 0.00s system 40% cpu 0.001 total
pbcopy  0.01s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 1.708 total
~❯ time pbpaste
test
pbpaste  0.01s user 0.01s system 1% cpu 0.860 total
~❯ time pbpaste
test
pbpaste  0.01s user 0.01s system 1% cpu 0.843 total
~❯ time pbpaste
test
pbpaste  0.01s user 0.01s system 1% cpu 0.853 total
```

If I watch Activity Monitor and set sampling to 1 second - I can see notifyd jump to 100% CPU usage everytime I run pbcopy.

If I kill `notifyd` pbcopy/paste works blazingly fast:

```
time echo 'test' | pbcopy
echo 'test'  0.00s user 0.00s system 38% cpu 0.002 total
pbcopy  0.01s user 0.01s system 80% cpu 0.015 total
```

El Capitan bug? Something else? Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reporting this directly to Apple via [bug reporter](http://bugreporter.apple.com) as it is unlikely anyone here will be able to help.

Delays of <strike>around point zero one</strike> less than one second are probably acceptable to Apple's engineers. 100% CPU is also acceptable; useful work is being done for the user when copying and pasting.

The pasteboard is not designed as a performance focused transport mechanism for processes and scripts.

Pasteboard operations can result in a cascade of notifications to processes. This is likely what you are detecting as `notifyd` is responsible for system wide notification delivery. This behaviour is normal.

Comment: I think you're missing the actual timing here: the wall clock time is `0.830 total`, `0.860 total`, etc.

Comment: You are right. I am an order of magnitude out. Still less than one second; which for a user initiated action remains acceptable.